# Node Express as proxy for a server that requires basic authentication

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, proxy, basic-authentication

So I'm using **express** and **express-http-proxy** as a proxy to an API web server that requires basic authentication. Then in my app, I'll be issuing Ajax calls to these APIs. After some effort I got this working but I'm sure there's a better way out there, hence this post.

Initially I set up the express proxy as follows:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

app.use('/apis', proxy("https://myserver", {
    forwardPath: function(req, res) {
      return "/apis" + require('url').parse(req.url).path;
    }
}));
```

When calling a URL directly in the browser (not via Ajax), eg. https://myserver/apis/myapi.ashx, I would see the authentication dialog asking me for my credentials, and I could authenticate and see the result.

However, when accessing the same URL via an Ajax call in my app, I was not getting a popup. Why this difference of behavior?

So I decided I needed to add my own basic authentication middleware using **request** and **basic-auth** as follows:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    proxy = require('express-http-proxy'),
    request = require('request'),
    basicAuth = require('basic-auth');

var myAuth = function (req, res, next) {
    function unauthorized(res) {
        res.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm=Rimes');
        return res.sendStatus(401);
    };

    var user = basicAuth(req);
    if (!user || !user.name || !user.pass) {
        return unauthorized(res);
    };

    var connectUrl = 'https://'+user.name+':'+user.pass+'@myserver/apis/connect.ashx';
    request.get(connectUrl, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            return next();
        } else {
            return unauthorized(res);
        }
    });
};

app.use('/apis', proxy("https://myserver", {
    forwardPath: function(req, res) {
        return "/apis" + require('url').parse(req.url).path;
    }
}));
```

This worked fine, showing me the authentication popup during the Ajax call.

The obvious disadvantage here is:

- Credential verification for every API request, although there may be a way to cache valid credentials. But in its defence, this is only on the development environment.

So is there a better way of doing this? Would a different middleware package do a better job?

Comment: A very popular middleware for handling authentication is [Passport.js](http://passportjs.org/). It includes authentication strategies for basic authentication, oauth, oauth2, Facebook login, Twitter login, and many more. I admit that it was a bit hard for me to wrap my head around at first, but when I did it was all worth it.

Comment: @Nocturno: Interesting, I'll take a deeper look. Appreciated